# How to display pdf file only in a portion of the browser using Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, pdf

I want to display PDF file on the object tag or iframe tag of the html, thymeleaf or whatever, I just want this to work. The PDF file is from the database. I tried using this code on the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/document/{cod}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity getFile(@PathVariable("cod") Integer cod) {
    Document document = documentRepository.find(cod);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=\"" + document.getFileName() + "\"")
            .body(document.getFile());
}
```

But that opens another window with a browser PDF preview, taking the entire page. So how can I display the pdf on the same page that I search for it? Since I have a search form, and below I want the PDF to appear, but without changing pages and occupying only one part of the page, and on the other part of the page the form will occupy. I am using spring boot and thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your UI code is already in place and working

You can load your response in any one of following elements. You can also manage the size of these elements.

**Option 1:**

```
<div>
    <object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
        alt : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
    </object>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**

```
<div>
  <iframe src="/pdf/test.pdf" style="width:100%;height:700px;"></iframe>
</div>
<div>

</div>
```

**Option 3:**

```
<embed src="pdfFiles/interfaces.pdf" width="600" height="500" alt="pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">
```